# NDepend Average Cyclomatic Complexity without get and set

Tags: ndepend

We are using NDepend 5 and I did have some doubts about our ***Average Cyclomatic Complexity***.

When checking how this query is made, I found out that it includes *getters* and *setters* of our properties. It seems to also includes auto properties methods. Those methodes are usually equivalent to a CC of 1. I don't like that because it lower our average CC and show us not the real average of methods we code.

Is there a way to remove properties from this calculation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom complexity metric with a [code query](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-syntax) that can be transformed into a rule if needed (with the prefix `warnif count > 0` and a threshold condition):

```
from t in JustMyCode.Types
let complexity = t.Methods.Where(m => !(m.IsPropertyGetter || m.IsPropertySetter))
                 .Sum(m => m.CyclomaticComplexity)
orderby complexity descending
select new { t, complexity, t.CyclomaticComplexity }
```

The screenshot below compares the obtained values.

[image: NDepend custom cyclomatic complexity]

Btw, NDepend v5 is not supported anymore and [v6](http://www.ndepend.com/ndepend-v6) and [v2017](http://www.ndepend.com/ndepend-v2017) brought a lot of new features.